# Undoing a git change where a file was renamed (deleted and added)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am working in Rails and I deleted a migration and added a migration with the same functionality because it needed to be placed ahead of a migration it was dependent on. In short, that resulted in a rename of this migration from say `"0001"` to `"0002"` which is essentially a delete of the migration `"0001"` and an addition of a migration named `"0002"`.

Say there's process at my company to not include migration changes in the PR that I'm currently working on. How do I revert these changes back? What do I do from here? How do I revert everything back to what it is on `master` ?

The changed files are the `schema.rb` and the two migration files... all of which are located in the `db` folder.

Comment: `git reset origin/master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `git revert` to create a new commit that undoes the changes or `git reset` to move your branch pointer to the commit before the move or `git rebase -i` to drop the commit from the history if you had commits after that, which you don't want to loose.